# Pandas read_csv method can't get 'œ' character properly while using encoding ISO 8859-15

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, encoding

I have some trubble reading with pandas a csv file which include the special character 'œ'.
I've done some reseach and it appears that this character has been added to the ISO 8859-15 encoding standard.

I've tried to specify this encoding standard to the pandas read_csv methods but it doesn't properly get this special character (I got instead a '☐') in the result dataframe :

`df= pd.read_csv(my_csv_path, ";", header=None, encoding="ISO-8859-15")`

Does someone know how could I get the right 'œ' character (or eaven better the string 'oe') instead of this ?

Thank's a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of facts, I've just tried to write down the dataframe than I get with the read_csv and ISO-8859-15 encoding (using pd.to_csv method and "ISO-8859-15" encoding) and the special 'œ' character properly appears in the result csv file... :

```
df.to_csv(my_csv_full_path, sep=';', index=False, encoding="ISO-8859-15")
```

So it seems that pandas has properly read the special character in my csv file but can't show it within the dataframe...

Answer (score 0):

Anyone have a clue ? I've manage the problem by manually rewrite this special character before reading my csv with pandas but that doesn't answer my question :(